# spark job result final status is undefined

Tags: apache-spark

After doing Spark installation one single node, on the same box I have installed Ambari server. I tried to validate one spark-job with Pi example:
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_spark-quickstart/content/run_spark_pi.html

Steps I tried

1. `su hdfs`
2. `cd /usr/hdp/current/spark-client`
3. `./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 1 lib/spark-examples*.jar 10

   [Note : I have changed excutors to 1 from 3 since i have only one data node running]

I was expected to see:

```
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: N/A
ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
queue: default
start time: 1428686924325
final status: SUCCEEDED

Log Type: stdout
Log Upload Time: 10-Jun-2015 17:13:33
Log Length: 23
Pi is roughly 3.142532
```

But running into an issue and I am seeing the following output:

```
client token: N/A
diagnostics: N/A
ApplicationMaster host: N/A
ApplicationMaster RPC port: **-1**
queue: default
start time: 1451540538466
final status: **UNDEFINED**
```

I also tried different Spark jobs. But, all are throwing same undefined status.

What am i missing? Appreciate you help.

Comment: The question was poorly formatted. For the steps, I added the formatting. For the output part, I formatted, so that it is readable.

Comment: @C.Sharma: 1. Check file permissions of user `hdfs` 2. Port `-1` sounds fishy ... also check network permissions. 3. Last, how did you make your first example work?

Comment: 1. hdfs user has all permissions. 2. For port -1 how do I check network permissions. 3. My examples are working only on interactive spark-shell only not via spark-submit. Thank you.